# Array using arrow operator and trying to push items in which order gets inserted?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

```js
basic = [['Answer', 'Votes']];
  (() => props.poll.answers.map(ans => basic.push([ans.answer, ans.votes])))();
```

I have one sentence as specified above into the one of my react files.
Could some one let me know what are the values getting inserted into the basic array and in which order
And into the map function what is the meaning of () as denoted into map function at the end.
basic.push([ans.answer, ans.votes]) Here the sentence is like this, Into the most of the scenario it would like array.push({name:value},{name,value}) but here into the square brackets what is the meaning of that.

Comment: This code would be better written as `basic = [['Answer', 'Votes']].concat(props.poll.answers.map(ans => [ans.answer, ans.votes]))`

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's split this question - essentially saying "what does this code do?" - in parts and answer each of them independently.

First of all, about syntax. The code in question is so-called [immediately-invoked function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), i.e. we *define* the function (the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), in this case) and then *call* it at the same line of code. That is, the second line could be simplified to:

```
  props.poll.answers.map(ans => basic.push([ans.answer, ans.votes]));
```

i.e. we remove the last parenthesis (the function call) and the ones before the arrow, with the arrow itself (so that only body of the function remains).

To make the original code somewhat more clear, we could also rewrite it as following:

```
const lambda = () => props.poll.answers.map(ans => basic.push([ans.answer, ans.votes]));
lambda();
```

Here, we explicitly store our function into variable (the name "lambda" is here to remind us that this function is, in fact, the [lambda-expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)) and then call it, using the variable name.

Now, for your questions.

---

#### "What are the values getting inserted into the basic array?"

Well, let's look at the code that is called by `map`:

```
ans => basic.push([ans.answer, ans.votes])
```

Here, we have the variable `ans` coming from the array we're mapping from. It is assumed that `ans` is an object, that has properties `answer` and `votes`. After that, these properties are combined into the two-element array, or, if you work with TypeScript, you'd call it a tuple [(scroll down a bit to see)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html), using the [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Creating_an_array) syntax.. This array, as a whole, is pushed into `basic`. For example, if we have the following `ans`:

```
ans = {answer: "Answer text", votes: 5};
```

and the `basic` created in your code, we's have the following after push:

```
basic === [['Answer', 'Votes'], ['Answer text', 5]]
```

As you can see, there's no harm in the array being inserted inside another array, they can be nested however you want.

#### "...and in which order?"

When any values are pushed into the array, they remain here exactly in the order they were pushed. The `map` function also iterates over the source array [preserving order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description). So, the elements in `basic` array would be in the same order as the corresponding elements of `answers`. Consider the following example:

```js
props = {
  poll: {
    answers: [
      {answer: 'Answer 1', votes: 1},
      {answer: 'Answer 2', votes: 20},
      {answer: 'Answer 1.5', votes: 2}
    ]
  }
};
basic = [['Answer', 'Votes']];
(() => props.poll.answers.map(ans => basic.push([ans.answer, ans.votes])))();
console.log(basic);
```

Let's check it step-by-step:

- `map` function gets the first element of array, `ans === {answer: 'Answer 1', votes: 1}`.
- The tuple is formed from `[ans.answer, ans.votes]`, i.e. `['Answer 1', 1]`.
- The tuple is inserted into `basic` array, `basic === [['Answer', 'Votes'], ['Answer 1', 1]]`.
- The second and third elements are processed in the same way.

You can check the result by running the snippet - `console.log()` was introduced exactly for that.

#### "What is the meaning of () as denoted into map function at the end?"

This question was already answered here, in fact, but I'd like to stress the following: **these parenthesis *aren't* connected with `map` in any way**. Let's format this expression:

```
(
  () => props.poll.answers.map(
    ans => basic.push([ans.answer, ans.votes])
  )
)();
```

You can see that `map` is inside the first parenthesis, because it is a part of function expression defined inside them. The parenthesis at the end are just calling this expression.

#### "Into the most of the scenario it would like `array.push({name:value},{name,value})`, but here into the square brackets - what is the meaning of that?"

Well, I'd rather not to speak about "most scenarios". There are many places where arrays are more convenient than objects (although here I'd probably stick to objects, if I was designing this code). And about you question - as was said before, the square brackets here denote an array literal, just like they do in `basic` definition.

Answer (score 0):

- what are the values getting inserted into the basic array
  The values that are being inserted, are contained inside props.poll.answers (which is an array)
- in which order
  Whatever order is in props.poll.answers

  - what is the meaning of the () as denoted into map function at the end.
    The () => denotes a function, in this case an anonymous function. The parentheses at the end indicates that is it a function that is to be executed immediately.

Some other things, basic is an array of arrays. So to keep the same object pattern, you would not want to push {name: value} as this would be an object. The square brackets indicate an array.